# Keycloak adding external SPI with Maven [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I build and package the project with maven for adding external SPI to Keycloak:

https://github.com/dasniko/keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator

I changed SNS to other API.But KC gives a following problem:

```
12:50:07,497 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-1) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
```

However I added org.json dependecy to my pom.xml while builded jar file.

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>dasniko</groupId>
  <artifactId>keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <finalName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.shade.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactSet>
                <includes>
                  <include>software.amazon.awssdk:*</include>
                  <include>org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams</include>
                  <include>org.json</include>
                </includes>
              </artifactSet>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
      <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi</artifactId>
      <version>20.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
      <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi-private</artifactId>
      <version>20.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20080701</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
      <artifactId>keycloak-services</artifactId>
      <version>20.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.dasniko</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spi-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    <aws.version>2.18.6</aws.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.10.1</maven.compiler.version>
    <maven.shade.version>3.2.4</maven.shade.version>
    <keycloak.version>20.0.0</keycloak.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>
```

What can be resolve such an issue ?

Answer (score 1):

There must be a problem with your jar not finding `org.json` library.

To check if it is there do the command:

`jar tf your-jar-file.jar | grep "org.json"`

If you are using powershell use

`jar tf your-jar-file.jar | Select-String "org.json"`

If it returns nothing, then the library is not added to the jar file.

What worked for me was to create a fat JAR using the `Maven Shade plugin` like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF 
                                  folder.
                                Otherwise, this might cause SecurityExceptions 
                                  when using the JAR. -->
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```